# Cast contract to address payable

Tags: solidity, address.transfer, type-casting

I am wondering if it is possible to cast a contract-reference to an address payable (in order to send to it money) or if it is possible to declare a contract-reference directly payable (with solidity > 0.5.0). So that the function `transfer` can be used.

To make the question more clear, I provide here a minimal example:

```
contract A {
     function() payable {
          // fallback logic goes here ...
     }
}

contract B {

    constructor() payable public {
        A a = new A();
        address payable receiver = address(a); // cast goes here
        receiver.transfer(msg.value);
     }
}
```

Concretely, how can I send money to A via transfer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works.

```
pragma solidity 0.5.1;

contract A {
     function() external payable {
          // fallback logic goes here ...
     }
}

contract B {

    constructor() payable public {
        A a = new A();
        address payable receiver = address(a); // cast goes here
        receiver.transfer(msg.value);
     }
}
```

Hope it helps.